# Где хранить и обрабатывать данные от игры на сайте? (Первый опыт создания)

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

Хочу создать игру 21 (JS, Django). У меня написан скрипт игры на Python, и я не знаю, как это реализовать. Пользователь нажимает на кнопки <Ещё> (выдать карту) и <Пас> (дилер начинает набирать карты, и по окончанию проверяется, кто выиграл).
Как работать с данными? При нажатии на кнопки отправлять ajax запрос на скрипт python, который будет выдавать случайную карту и так далее? Как быть при следующих запросах, ведь при повторной отправке python скрипт будет заново выдавать карту из той же колоды, не учитывая карты, которые уже были (нужно передавать данные в ajax какие карты уже есть и переписать логику скрипта на python?) и как безопасно это хранить, чтобы пользователь не мог подделать данные.
Я думаю, что надо создать таблицу раунда и при каждой отправке ajax сверять данные от клиента и бд. Первый опыт в этом и сложно описать свой вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто не делайте никаких операций на клиентской части. Все проверки производите на серверной стороне. Таким образом, если человек подделает свои данные, храня информацию о ходе игры на серверы вы быстро об этом узнаете и сможете принять необходимые меры

Что касается определения раунда игроков - связываете пользователя (если авторизован) с раундом (модель) либо храните ключи сессий пользователей и/или связывайте уже их с раундом. Как получить ключ сессии можете узнать несложным поиском и/ли в документации django в соответствующем разделе